# EJS file not rendering as expected

Tags: html, ejs

I'm having an issue with an EJS file not rendering as expected. I'm using ExpressJS and MongoDB. When I fetch the data from the DB it is rendered to the page, but none of the HTML from the EJS template is being rendered. I suspect the issue is with my router.get() call, but I've been unable to troubleshoot it thus far.

My current code is as follows:

**Index.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET Userlist page */
router.get("/userlist", function (req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get("usercollection");
  collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
    res.render("userlist", {
      "userlist": docs
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**userlist.ejs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    User List
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    User List
  </h1>
  <ul>
    <% var list = ''; 
      for (i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) { 
        list += '<li><a href="mailto:' + userlist[i].email + '">' + userlist[i].username + '</a></li>'; 
      } 
        return list; 
    %>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

If anyone can identify the syntax error and suggest a correction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your ejs file. Try this loop:

```
<ul>
<% for (var item of userlist) { %>
    <li><a href="mailto:<%= item.email %>"><%= item.username %></a></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: So your suggestion is a working replacement for the ejs code I had used previously, but unfortunately I still have the issue of the other HTML not rendering.